# Chromatic number of the complete graph after removing 3 vertex disjoint edges

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

[image]

I am tasked to determine the chromatic number of the complete graph after removing 3 vertex disjoint edges on n or more vertices.

I have found an upper bound by using brooks theorem since the graph is not regular nor an odd cycle then it is bounded from above by the maximum degree i.e. n-1

I am struggling to find a lower bound

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume WLOG that the vertex-set is written as $V=\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$, and that the edges removed are $v_{n-4}v_{n-5}$, $v_{n-2}v_{n-3}$, and $v_nv_{n-1}$. On the one hand, note that the coloring $c: V \mapsto \{1,\ldots, n-3\}$, where

1. $c(v_i) = i$ for each $i=1,\ldots, n-6$;
2. $c(v_{n-5})=c(v_{n-4})=n-5$;
3. $c(v_{n-3})=c(v_{n-2})=n-4$; and
4. $c(v_{n-1})=c(v_{n})=n-3$;

is a proper coloring of $H_n$, and uses only $n-3$ colors $1,2,\ldots, n-3$. So $\chi(H_n)$ is no larger than $n-3$.

On the other hand, note that the induced subgraph of $H_n$ on $S=\{v_1,\ldots, v_{n-6},v_{n-5},v_{n-3},v_{n-1}\}$ [equivalently, $S$ is the first $n-6$ vertices of $H_n$, plus exactly one vertex from each of the $3$ edges removed, so $S$ has $(n-6)+3$ $=$ $n-3$ vertices total] is still the complete graph. So for any proper coloring of $H_n$, each of the vertices in $S$ must receive a different color. As $S$ has $n-3$ vertices then, it follows that at least $n-3$ colors are needed to properly color $H_n$, so $\chi(H_n)$ is at least $n-3$.

From the above paragraphs, $n-3$ is both an upper- and lower-bound for $\chi(H_n)$, so $\chi(H_n)$ is exactly $n-3$.

Comment: That's great thank you! I am strugglign to see how S is the complete graph on n-3 vertices though? Is there any way to show this? I have drawn K7 and I'm able to find a K4 subgraph however Im not sure how to justify this for general n

Comment: @Billy Every two vertices in $S$ were joined by an edge in the original complete graph (before you removed 3 edges), and none of those edges between vertices in $S$ were removed.

Comment: You can check to see that in $H_n$, for any $2$ vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$, in $S$ there still an edge between $v_i$ and $v_j$, i.e., the edge between $v_i$ and $v_j$ in $K_n$ was not removed to make $H_n$.